# How to remove entire row in excel when conditions are met

Tags: vba, excel

The program I am working on involves reading and determining the difference between i - (i+1)and i-(i-1) form excel. If the difference exceeds 4 then the program deletes the row at i. The program works well at the first try. However, when I repeat it again it starts deleting points that should not be deleted.

Option Explicit

Sub Data_Delet()

```
Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, i As Double
Dim rkill As Range
' a,b, and c are used as steps in order to proceed to the next data points
a = 18
b = 0
c = 0

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' The second do loop delete data points that does not follow the requirements
    Do
    If Abs(.Cells(a - 1, 2) - .Cells(a, 2)) > 4 And Abs(.Cells(a, 2) - .Cells(a + 1, 2)) > 4 Then
         If rkill Is Nothing Then
            Set rkill = Rows(a)
         Else
            Set rkill = Union(rkill, Rows(a))
         End If
    End If
    a = a + 1
    Loop Until .Cells(a, 2).Value = ""
    rkill.EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
rkill.EntireRow.Delete
```

to

```
If Not rkill is Nothing Then rkill.EntireRow.Delete
```

This code checks if the range `rkill` is a `range` and then it deletes it. If it is not a range then it will not execute the latter part.

An alternative would be (Which I don't suggest)

```
On Error Resume Next
rkill.EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```